# How to Uninstall the lollipop app

Tags: adb

Could you please tell me how to go back to my old android? I have a Samsung S5 and I tried the factory reset and that did not work. I hate this new android version

Comment: this is `Lollipop Rom`, not `app`. can you tell us, this is Stock or Custom Rom?

Comment: What carrier are you with? It's possible to download the ROM for the previous version and flash it, but doing so will wipe all data on your phone. As well, all future support from Samsung for your phone, including updates, new features, and security patches will be released ONLY for Lollipop. It's likely far better for you to attempt to adjust to the changes or ask for help in resolving the ones you don't like than to roll back to an older, unsupported version.

Answer (score 0):

Download previous firmware.
Try samfirmware.com
Use odin to flash it.
And you will be back to stock and dont forget to back up your data